# Dynamically change image in jquery based on dropdown selection and insert into div

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a drop down list that I would like to display its accompanying image upon selection (i.e. if 'Option 1' is selected, 'Image 1' should be displayed - - so on and so forth)

Here is the following code. Currently in div1 the result is "undefined". I think I'm close, but my jquery is not the greatest.

HTML FORM:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" name="newItem" id="newItem">
    <select id="searchresults" required>
        <option data-src="images/test/Option_1_50.png">Option 1</option>
        <option data-src="images/test/Option_2_50.png">Option 2</option>
        <option data-src="images/test/Option_3_50.png">Option 3</option>
        <option data-src="images/test/Option_4_50.png">Option 4</option>        
    </select>
</form>

<input type="button" id="addItem" onclick="clear" value="Add Program" />
<button type="reset" id="reset">Reset Search</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#addItem").click(function(){
  var task = $('#searchresults').val();
  var src = $(this).attr('data-src');
  $("#tasks").append("<li><div1>" + src + "</div1><div2>" + task + "</div2><button class='up'>&#x2191</button><button class='down'>&#x2193</button></li>");
});
```

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: What is `#addItem`?  Also here is no php in question that is javascript

Comment: sorry that was a typo! I will edit.

Comment: updated the code with the #addItem id - was just for a button upon submit

Comment: @MichaelPhilibin please think of [accepting an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

1. There's no value in your options.

Should be like this:

```
<option data-src="images/test/Option_1_50.png" val="val_1">Option 1</option>
```

2. Your `src` is targeting `$(this)` which is the `addItem` button that's why you're getting `undefined`.

To fix:

```
var src = $('#searchresults').find(':selected').attr('data-src');
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wvkhzv1j/)

**Update**

Since you want to display the actual image instead of the image path.
Do it like this:

```
$("#addItem").click(function() {
  var task = $('#searchresults').val();
  var src = $('#searchresults').find(':selected').attr('data-src');
  $("#tasks").append("<li><div><img src=" + src + "/></div><div>" + task + "</div><button class='up'>&#x2191</button><button class='down'>&#x2193</button></li>");
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wvkhzv1j/1/)

Comment: still receiving undefined

Comment: @MichaelPhilibin That's weird. Check how it is implemented [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wvkhzv1j/) and it's working

Comment: saw it was working there, but on my end it is displaying the image path text (image/test/option_1_50./png) instead of the image itself and the text (val_1) is being displayed over top of the text Option 1, which is what I want displayed.

Comment: @MichaelPhilibin Ahh I see, so you want to show the actual image instead of the text. See updated answer.

Comment: when i try to implement code, still not showing my image, shows the image icon but not the image itself...my hosting connection is very shotty too making this difficult!!

Comment: is it necessary to call option   val="val_1" when i have Option_1 as the value?

Comment: @MichaelPhilibin Ok, that's some progress though. I think the problem is the image path was incorrect.

Comment: @MichaelPhilibin Yes it's necessary to put your val on value attribute since that's  where it will be getting the val. So just change it to `val="Option_1"`

Comment: ok. well ive only displayed a million images on a website before so not sure whats up with the path. its in public_html>images>test>blah.png

Comment: @MichaelPhilibin Can you check on your console tab, if you're seeing any errors there?

Comment: console tab? what you mean exactly?

Comment: but, i think we have it solved i just need to figure out why the path is not correct

Comment: would it have anything to do with the image tagged to the option as a data-src and not img src?

Comment: @MichaelPhilibin Yeah, check [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b_F9slIjMiY) for opening console tab.

Comment: ahh no, since we were getting the path value using `.attr('data-src');`

Comment: Robin Carlo Catacutan finally found time to check console. Receiving these errors: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () & Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: @MichaelPhilibin Ahh I see, so there seems to be a problem with the paths

Comment: would it have anything to do with operating on .shtml page? Also had .htaccess rewritten for https security. Baffled because I have other images displaying just fine...I can display image fine if coded into the page itself. However, once implement jquery, the images are inaccessible

Comment: @MichaelPhilibin Ahh right, of course! Nice spotting that!

Answer (score 0):

You want the data-src from the selected option not from whatever `#addItem` (note it is not shown in your code).

Use a change event on the select:

```js
$("#searchresults").change(function() {
  var $sel = $(this),
    task = $sel.val(),
    src = $sel.find(':selected').attr('data-src');
  $("#tasks").append("<li><div1>" + src + "</div1><div2>" + task + "</div2><button class='up'>&#x2191</button><button class='down'>&#x2193</button></li>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="searchresults" required>
        <option data-src="images/test/Option_1_50.png">Option 1</option>
        <option data-src="images/test/Option_2_50.png">Option 2</option>
        <option data-src="images/test/Option_3_50.png">Option 3</option>
        <option data-src="images/test/Option_4_50.png">Option 4</option>        
    </select>
<ul id="tasks"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your context, `$(this)` refers to the `<select>` and not the specific option. The `<select>` gets sets a `value` attribute, but does not get any other custom attribute you set.

So you need to get a reference to the currently *selected* `<option>` element, as in the code below:

```
$("#searchresults").change(function(evt) {
    var src = $(this).find(':selected').attr('data-src');
    $("#theimage").attr("src", src);
});
```

You should use something like this (I am assuming you have some `<img id="theimage">` somewhere).

Comment: don't specifically have an image id, where would you assume this would be? within the option tag?

Comment: this method seems to invalidate my "addItem" submit buttom

Answer (score 0):

Remove `div1` and `div2` tags and `this` refers to the clicked button, use the id of the `select` instead and use [$.data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to get values from custom attributes.

```js
$("#addItem").click(function(){
        var task = $('#searchresults').val();
        var src = $('#searchresults').find(":selected").data('src');
        $("#tasks").append("<li><div><img src='" + src + "'/></div><div2>" + task + "</div2><button class='up'>&#x2191</button><button class='down'>&#x2193</button></li>");
    });
```

```css
img {
    width: 200px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="test.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" name="newItem" id="newItem">
    <select id="searchresults" required>
        <option data-src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/67660/pexels-photo-67660.jpeg">Option 1</option>
        <option data-src="https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/147083304-dogs-home-alone-all-day-632x475.jpg">Option 2</option>
        <option data-src="https://lh5.ggpht.com/wTqjSLMWjdRjsOcJogqOBLR-Vj41v55uSi7QrCFoSKm62sq_anxz3eK5uf_gMq7ApslJ=h900">Option 3</option>
        <option data-src="ihttps://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--kx3d-Wgg--/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/ol9ceoqxidudap8owlwn.jpg">Option 4</option>
    </select>
</form>
<input type="button" id="addItem" onclick="clear" value="Add Program" />
<button type="reset" id="reset">Reset Search</button>

<div id="tasks"></div>
```